# Uniqueness of solution based on characteristic curves

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I have a pde 
$$\begin{cases} u_t − xu_x = 2u & x\in\mathbb{R}, t>0\\ 
u(x, 0) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}
\end{cases}$$

I've solved it using method of characteristics ($u=\frac{1}{1+x^2e^{2t}}e^{2t})$ and plotted charactersitic curves.[image]

Consider the upper half-space since $t>0$.
How to argue using the drawing whether or not it is the unique solution? Thank you.

Comment: Are you plotting in the $(t, u)$ plane? $(x, u)$? $(t, x)$?

Comment: @Mattos This is the projection on the $(x,t)$-plane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method of characteristics transforms the PDE into an ODE system. Therefore, existence and uniqueness is guaranteed under the assumptions of the [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).